Inverse system of units
Let $(R_i, \varphi_{ij})_{i\in \mathbb{Z}^+}$ be an inverse system of rings satisfying Mittag-Leffler condition, and each $\ker(\varphi_{i+1, i})$ being a nilpotent ideal. Then does $(R_i^*, \varphi_{ij}^*)$, the inverse system of units, also satisfies Mittag-Leffler condition? I tried straightforward ways but didn't work.
This comes from exercise II.9.6(a) of Hartshorne. Here is the original formulation: Let $\mathfrak{X}$ be a noetherian formal scheme, and $\mathfrak{I}$ be an ideal of definition, and for each $n$, let $Y_n$ be the scheme $(\mathfrak{X}, \mathcal{O}_{\mathfrak{X}}/\mathfrak{I}^n)$. Assume that the inverse system of groups $\Gamma(Y_n, \mathcal{O}_{Y_n})$ satisfies the Mittag-Leffler condition. Use the fact that $\ker(\Gamma(Y_{n+1}, \mathcal{O}_{Y_{n+1}})\to \Gamma(Y_n, \mathcal{O}_{Y_n}))$ is a nilpotent ideal to show that the inverse system $\Gamma(Y_n, \mathcal{O}_{Y_n}^*)$ of units also satisfies (ML).
I thought it should be easy but nothing works. Can anyone please help me?

Well, it was stupid to just convert into an algebraic statement. We should note that affine-locally the natural map is a surjection $A/I^{n+1}\to A/I^n$, and here the kernel squares to zero, so we see that only unit can be mapped to unit. If $s\in\Gamma(Y_{n+1},\mathcal{O}_{n+1})$ maps to a unit, as $s|_U$ glues well, we can also glue local inverses $s|_U^{-1}$, and it follows that $s$ is a unit. Now (ML) on inverse system implies (ML) of inverse system of units.
